# Auto-position CSS Tooltip according to element?

Tags: css, tooltip

I have built this CSS tool tip:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/x02exd59/)

CSS:

```
.help {
    position: relative
}

.help .help-text {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FDFCEF;
    border: 1px solid #E8E5C1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: normal;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2
}

.help .help-text:after,
.help .help-text:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    left: 13%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none
}

.help .help-text:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #FDFCEF;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px
}

.help .help-text:before {
    border-color: transition transition #E8E5C1;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px
}

.help:hover .help-text {
    display: block
}

.help-text {
    width: 185px
}

.help-icon {
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #789cbf;
    font-size: .9em!important;
    vertical-align: 0!important;
    cursor: help
}

.other {
    display: inline
}

p.inline {
    display: inline-block
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block
}

.box {
    font-size: .65em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #00cc4f;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 97px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    cursor: help
}
```

HTML:

```
  <table border="1">
    <col style="width:128px;" />
    <col style="width:216px;" />
    <col style="width:280px;" />   
            <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="inline">Sample A</p><span class="help"><span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span><div class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div></span>

               <span class="help"><div class="box">SAMPLE BOX</div><div class="help-text">im ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div></span>


            <div>aaa</div>                                                
            <div class="other">Sample B</div><span class="help"><span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span><div class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div></span>                    
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td><ul>
              <li class="inline">Another Sample: C</li>
              <span class="help">
              <span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span>
              <div class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
              </span>
              <li class="inline">Yet Another Great Sample - D:</li>
              <span class="help">
              <span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span>
              <div class="help-text">r sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dol ssssssssssssssss</div>
              </span>      
              </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>     
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

As you can see, for each sample the positioning comes out different.

I want it to be positioned according to the element containing the tip.

Also, is this code a good practice? does it work well on tablet as well? or should I some modification?

Also, is it better to use a java script based tool-tip? If so, which is the closest to my current one?

Comment: Is this what you look for: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/x02exd59/1/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. UL can only have LI as children.

Comment: @LGSon , Yes, this seems to work just as I need. Thank you. Is this a good practice? Is it cross-browser compliant?

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you mean I should place the `SPAN` before closing `LI`?

Comment: That would be normal yes.

Comment: I posted an answer for you, and it is a good solution, cross browser (down to IE8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `margin-left: 60px; margin-top: 12px;` to `left: -15px; top: calc(100% + 5px);`

*I also corrected the syntax error having `span` as a direct child of `ul`*

```css
.help {
    position: relative
}

.help .help-text {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FDFCEF;
    border: 1px solid #E8E5C1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: normal;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    left: -15px;
    top: calc(100% + 5px);
    line-height: 1.2
}

.help .help-text:after,
.help .help-text:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    left: 13%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none
}

.help .help-text:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #FDFCEF;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px
}

.help .help-text:before {
    border-color: transition transition #E8E5C1;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px
}

.help:hover .help-text {
    display: block
}

.help-text {
    width: 185px
}

.help-icon {
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #789cbf;
    font-size: .9em!important;
    vertical-align: 0!important;
    cursor: help
}

.other {
    display: inline
}

p.inline {
    display: inline-block
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block
}

.box {
    font-size: .65em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #00cc4f;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 97px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    cursor: help
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <table border="1">
        <col style="width:128px;" />
        <col style="width:216px;" />
        <col style="width:280px;" />   
                <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="inline">Sample A</p><span class="help"><span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span><div class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div></span>
                
                   <span class="help"><div class="box">SAMPLE BOX</div><div class="help-text">im ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div></span>
                  
                  
                <div>aaa</div>                                                
                <div class="other">Sample B</div><span class="help"><span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span><div class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div></span>                    
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td><ul>
                  <li class="inline">Another Sample: C
                  <span class="help">
                  <span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span>
                  <div class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
                  </span></li>
                  <li class="inline">Yet Another Great Sample - D:
                  <span class="help">
                  <span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span>
                  <div class="help-text">r sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dol ssssssssssssssss</div>
                  </span></li>
                  </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>     
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not related to your code, I noticed that because I chose to display the pop-box to the left side, on tablets it will get cut off. Therefore I will change `left` of `help-text:before` to `55%` (instead of `13%`) and in your code I will change accordingly `left` of .help .help-text to `-100px` (instead of `-15px`. I just wonder why do I have to use such a big negative number in order to make it work? Is there a better practice?

Comment: @rockyraw Better practice: Yes and No ... Using `position:absolute` gives you the ability to position it exactly where you want, downside is when hitting browser edge, it might be positioned off view. To fix that so a user won't have to scroll, one can add a script on the elements having a help text, which adjust the left value if it goes out of view. ... Big negative number: The tooltip need to move that much to the left for the "arrow" to point at the `?` sign

Answer (score 0):

Set .help-text inside .fa-question-circle. This way help text will be positioned relative to its parent element. Then you just have to change margin-left to -20px and you're done.

```
<div class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon">
  <span class="help-text">r sit amet, </span>
 </div>
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/co0xLaro/)'s the working fiddle. first two tooltips are unchanged, the other two are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/x02exd59/3/ .

First I made some HTML changes. Your absolute positioned element (the tooltip text) will display relative to its parent. This means that if we make the glyphicon its parent, it will display based on where the icon is.

Secondly I checked the CSS to make sure the glyphicon had position: relative; and the info-text had position: absolute;.

Thirdly I fine-tuned the placement of the info-text with the top: and left: values. (I also changed the position of the arrow element you created to left:25px.)

**HTML**

```
  <table border="1">
    <col style="width:128px;" />
    <col style="width:216px;" />
    <col style="width:280px;" />   
            <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="inline">Sample A</p><i class="help fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"><span class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.</span></i>

               <div class="help box">SAMPLE BOX<span class="help-text">im ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</span></div>


            <div>aaa</div>                                                
            <div class="other">Sample B<span class="help fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"><span class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</span></span></div>                    
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td><ul>
              <li class="inline">Another Sample: C</li>
              <span class="help">
              <span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span>
              <div class="help-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
              </span>
              <li class="inline">Yet Another Great Sample - D:</li>
              <span class="help">
              <span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-lg help-icon"></span>
              <div class="help-text">r sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. bore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dol ssssssssssssssss</div>
              </span>      
              </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>     
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.help {
    position: relative
    ;
}

.help .help-text {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FDFCEF;
    border: 1px solid #E8E5C1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: normal;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2
}

.help .help-text:after,
.help .help-text:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    left: 25px;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none
}

.help .help-text:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent #FDFCEF;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px
}

.help .help-text:before {
    border-color: transition transition #E8E5C1;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.help:hover .help-text {
    display: block
}

.help-text {
    width: 185px
}

.help-icon {
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #789cbf;
    font-size: .9em!important;
    vertical-align: 0!important;
    cursor: help
}

.other {
    display: inline
}

p.inline {
    display: inline-block
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block
}

.box {
    font-size: .65em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #00cc4f;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 97px;
    height: 18px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    cursor: help
}
```